# How can I convert an optical mouse into an optical flow sensor?

Tags: sensor

I'm working on a rover.I'm using it with Raspberry Pi as my microprocessor.And can anyone tell me that whether i need an encoder with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the raw mouse data from /dev/input/mouse0.
Library to access these is evdev. Its accessible it with [python](http://pythonhosted.org/evdev/), or [C/C++](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/).
For more Information see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060710/format-of-dev-input-event.